# Solving $T(n) = \frac{1}{n}(T(0)+T(1)+...+T(n-1)) + cn$ for all $ n \geq 1$

Tags: recurrence-relation

Solving $T(n) = \frac{1}{n}(T(0)+T(1)+...+T(n-1)) + cn$ for all $ n \geq 1$

Subbing few numbers in we get

$T(1) = T(0)/1 + c(1)$

$T(2) = \frac{T(0)+T(1)}{2} + c(2) $

Which is kind of going backwards as I am going back to finding T(n)

So I am kind of confused about it, any idea?

Are we even able to unroll this reccurence?

Comment: You didn't define T(0).

Comment: Use a spreadsheet to show the first 100 values, given some T(0) and c. Form a hypothesis. Prove the hypothesis. Instead of "I tried to think and nothing happened", use "I entered the numbers in a spreadsheet and got an idea".